# Call nls from within a function in R, passing a user-specified function with any number of arguments

Tags: r, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions, nls, flexibility

I have a function that uses `stats::nls()` internally to get parameter estimates for a non-linear model. However, the number of parameters I need the function to estimate is variable and determined by the users. How can I do this? This function is going in an R package, so it is important that it is as flexible as possible.

For example, here is some dummy data and two possible functions that users might use.

```
## dummy data
set.seed(654)
df <- data.frame(d = runif(50))
df$y <- exp(-df$d/.1)
df$x <- df$y + abs(rnorm(50, sd = .2))
## functions with different numbers of arguments
exp_fun <- function(d, r){
  return(exp(-d/r))
}
exppow_fun <- function(d, r, a){
  return(exp(-(d/r)^a))
}
```

The goal is to have a function called `fit_nls()`, which takes at least 3 arguments, `x`, `d`, and `FUN`. `FUN` is a function that takes `d` as its first argument, but can have any number of additional parameters, and outputs some transformation of `d`:

```
# run with any FUN
fit_nls(d = df$d, x = df$x, FUN = "exp_fun", ...)
fit_nls(d = df$d, x = df$x, FUN = "exppow_fun", ...)
fit_nls(d = df$d, x = df$x, FUN = function(d, a, b, c, e){...}), ...)
fit_nls(d = df$d, x = df$x, FUN = function(d){...}, ...)
```

I can make the function work for a fixed number of arguments:

```
fit_nls <- function(d, x, FUN, start){
  fit.fun <- match.fun(FUN)
  nls(x ~ fit.fun(d, r = r), start = start)
}

fit_nls(df$d, df$x,  "exp_fun", start = list(r = .1))
fit_nls(df$d, df$x,  function(d, r){d^r}, start = list(r = .1))
```

but haven't been able to figure out how to use a variable number of parameters. One thing I've tried is passing a list of arguments using `do.call()`, but this doesn't work:

```
fit_nls.multiarg <- function(d, x, FUN, start){
  fit.fun <- match.fun(FUN)
  args = append(list(d = d), start)
  nls(x ~ do.call(fit.fun, args), start = start)
}
fit_nls.multiarg(df$d, df$x, "exp_fun", list(r = .01)) # error
```

which isn't really surprising, since it is equivalent to setting the values within the function:

```
nls(df$x ~ exp_fun(df$d, r = .1), start = list(r = .01) # equivalent error
```

So, I tried passing a symbol as a stand-in, without success:

```
fit_nls.symbol <- function(d, x, FUN, start){
  fit.fun <- match.fun(FUN)
  nam = names(start)
  args = append(list(d = d), as.symbol(nam))
  nls(x ~ do.call(fit.fun, args), start = start)
}

fit_nls.symbol(df$d, df$x, "exp_fun", list(r = .01)) # error
```

I'm open to any kind of solution. If anyone can give me any advice or point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The usual way to do this is to write your functions with a single list argument and then pull indexed items from that list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a character string or function name is passed set FUN to the name of the function as a character string; otherwise, use "fit.fun". Then create the formula argument as a character string, convert it to an actual R formula and then run nls.

```
fit_nls <- function(d, x, FUN, start) {
  FUN <- if (length(match.call()[[4]]) > 1) {
    fit.fun <- match.fun(FUN)
    "fit.fun"
  } else deparse(substitute(FUN)) 
  fo <- as.formula(sprintf("x ~ %s(d, %s)", FUN, toString(names(start))))
  nls(fo, start = start)
}
```

Tests

```
with(df, fit_nls(d, x, "exp_fun", list(r = .01)))
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: x ~ exp_fun(d, r)
##    data: parent.frame()
##      r 
## 0.1968 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.319
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.254e-06

with(df, fit_nls(d, x,  function(d, r){d^r}, start = list(r = .1)))
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: x ~ fit.fun(d, r)
##    data: parent.frame()
##     r 
## 96.73 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 4.226
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 22 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.429e-06

with(df, fit_nls(d, x, exp_fun, list(r = .01)))
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: x ~ exp_fun(d, r)
##    data: parent.frame()
##      r 
## 0.1968 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 1.319
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 11 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.254e-06
```

Comment: nls cannot be run without any parameters.

Comment: This works for cases where the number of parameters in `FUN` is greater than 0 (p > 0). You only show the p = 1 case in your comment, but I also tested p = 2: `with(df, fit_nls(d, x, "exppow_fun", list(r = .1, a = .2)))`, and it works as well. I'm not sure if the p = 0 case would actually be useful for users anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks again.